# power to outlet until something is plugged in

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have a single item on the line.  I have power on that line until I plug something in and then I lose power to that outlet.  I replaced both the circuit breaker and outlet.  Suggestions please.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. If you lose power when you plug something in, *how do you know there was power there before?* What is your testing method that shows power?  Is it a voltmeter, and if so what voltage does it show?

Comment: Does the breaker trip or does the outlet just stop working?

Comment: Have you tried plugging different things into the outlet? The item that you're plugging in might have an issue. Also, is there a GFCI or AFCI in use?

Comment: Sounds like a failed back stab , if using a non contact tester and with a load there is no power it’s a damaged splice or backstab. If a non contact tester says there is power but a load is plugged in and it doesn’t work it’s the neutral.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the breaker doesn’t trip and there isn’t a GFCI involved, this would generally indicate a poor, high resistance, connection somewhere in the line. Your voltmeter pulls so little current that you see the full voltage but when you connect a real load, the poor connection drops the voltage.

Since you replaced the breaker and outlet, the problem must be elsewhere. Wires generally don’t just fail, unless someone drove a nail through it. So you are looking for a junction box somewhere with splices. At least hopefully, the person who wires it followed code and didn’t just splice it in a wall.